# Kubuntu 13.10 no sound, missing shutdown button, network disconnected

Tags: updates, kubuntu, 13.10

I just updated to Kubuntu 13.10 and several things are wrong. For instance, the only output sound device is Dummy Output, network icon has a red X on it and shutdown and restart buttons are missing. What is wrong?

Comment: Half of this answer is duplicate, agreed. But I also asked a second question, which is not.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of it? Also, the output of `nm-tool`

Comment: that guy below answered it for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I had the same thing happen to me.  I didn't know it but my upgrade to Kubuntu 13.10 got interrupted.  When I ran the apt-get command, it told me it was interrupted and the command to run.  Try this command first:

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

It seemed to work for me, my network icon had a red x, my shutdown and restart buttons were gone, and my sound wouldn't work.  After I ran the command, it all came back after I re-booted.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with my audio not working after upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10 as well.

For me it turned out to simply be the "sound settings" (upper right of screen, click on the speaker for volume control and select sound settings) default output was set to "HDMI / DisplayPort" which happened to go to a monitor that didn't have speakers attached.

Simple audio default fix. Would have been nice if the upgrade didn't kill my default settings, now I'm curious how many other things got messed up in the transition.

This is the kind of simple user friendliness problem that keeps me from recommending Ubuntu to 100% of people.

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been fixed.

```
sudo pam-auth-update --force
```

did the trick.

Please see also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1185592